Windows.Services.Store.Store.StoreContext does not send notification of optional application updates
Discovered the problem while working with application updates in UWP/WinUI3. If I upload a new version of the application as optional updates and disable auto-updates in Microsoft Store, the code below retrieves only mandatory updates. It seems optional updates are not being returned by GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync.
Code snippet
private StoreContext context = null;
public async Task DownloadAndInstallAllUpdatesAsync()
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        context = StoreContext.GetDefault();
    }

    // Get the updates that are available.
    IReadOnlyList<StorePackageUpdate> updates =
        await context.GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync();
}

What I tried:

Checked app package versions and optional package flags.
Verified Store configuration for auto-updates.
Ensured GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync is used correctly.

Question:

Are there any known limitations in GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync when retrieving optional updates?
Is there an alternative method or configuration to fetch optional updates?
Any suggestions or clarifications are welcome.


Could you please explain that is the optional updates hat you mean? Is it the normal updates for your app? The GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync returns when there are update for your app, or when there are optional packages available.

@RoyLi-MSFT, By updates, I mean new versions of the app that are published. There are two types of updates: mandatory and optional, you want users to receive an in-app notification when a new non-mandatory update is available

So it means a normal update that doesn't check the mandatory checkbox, right?  Does the update increase the version number? If not, then GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync won't know there is an update.

@RoyLi-MSFT, Yes, that's correct, this is an update that does not have the mandatory checkbox checked. I think you are right in that GetAppAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync does not recognize the presence of the update. What could be the reason and are there any solutions to this problem?

As I mentioned above, the GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync returns when the version changes. Even it is just a normal update, you will need to increase the version number as well.

@RoyLi-MSFT,  With each certification the version is necessarily increased, if the version is not changed, the dashboard shows an error and does not allow to update packages.

Could you please create a blank project with a lower version to see if this behavior could be reproduced in the new project? Another question is that does this happens on different machine?

And this behavior only happens when the auto updates feature is disabled in the Store app right?

@RoyLi-MSFT, Yes, this behavior happens on different machines and when auto-updates are disabled in the Microsoft Store

I have to say that I can't reproduce this behavior on my VM with the auto-updates is disabled. The API will return the correct value when the version of the app is lower than the version in the Store. Do you get any error or exception when calling this API? Also, are you associating to the correct app?
